# DRF update or create object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

guys in my app each product must have only one record for discount in table.
i have this view for create new record in db .. how can i tell if object with comming product id is availible in db just update the target column otherwise create new object ? some people use def create in serializer  should i use that function or something else ???

```
class DiscountControllAPiView(APIView):
    """
        each product may takes a discount code or percent from owner or site administrator
    """
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(data=request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(True)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

related serilizer :

```
class ProductDiscountControllSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductDiscountControll
        fields = [
            'product',
            'discount',
            'discount_code',
            'discount_code_precent',
        ]
```

Comment: What about, `ModelName.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)` ?

Comment: [Django get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: let me check that thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class DiscountControllAPiView(APIView):
    """
        each product may takes a discount code or percent from owner or site administrator
    """
    def post(self,request):
        id = request.data.get('id', None):
        if not id:
            # perform creation
            serializer = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(data=request.data)
        else:
            # perform updation
            product_discount_controll = ProductDiscountControll.objects.get(id=int(id))
            serializer = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(product_discount_controll, data=request.data)

        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(True)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

If `id` is present in the request, the api will update else it will create new record